# What those $variable->$variable in OOP php do?

Tags: php, oop

I am following a tutorial and have come across the following code in defining a user class:

```
class User {

public $id;
public $username;
public $password;
public $first_name;
public $last_name;

public static function instantiate($record) {

    $object = new self;

    foreach ($record as $attribute => $value){
        if ($object->has_attribute($attribute)){
            $object->$attribute = $value;
        }
    }

    return $object;

}

private function has_attribute($attribute) {

    $object_vars = get_object_vars($this);
    return array_key_exists($attribute, $object_vars);

    }
}
```

My question is: What does the "$object->$attribute = $value;" do exactly ?

I am just starting in OOP php and I am really confuse of what that bit of code is downing.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's addressing property of an object `$object`, which name is stored in `$attribute`.

Comment: Have to say I really wonder what's wrong with using `__set()` here instead.

Comment: @raina77ow It seems OP is following a tutorial, which might be written in depreciated code or by someone who considers them-self knowledgeable in the field so started writing non-optimized tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an assignment statement for an attribute of the PHP class. Let's use a less ambiguous example. We will create a small person class that holds a first name and a last name.

```
class Person
{
    //Class attributes
    public $fisrtName;
    public $lastName;
}
```

Using the above example, if you wanted to set those attributes, you would do the following:

```
//Instantiate a new person
$myPerson = new Person();

//Assign values to the person object
$myPerson->firstName = "John";
$myPerson->lastName = "Smith";
```

Alternately, if you wanted to assign the value myPerson object's firstName field to a different variable, you could do the following:

```
$personsName = $myPerson->firstName;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your explanation made it crystal clear for me. Your answer was just what I was looking for to get around the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty basic question : it is assigning the value `$value` to the attribute `$attribute` of the object `$object`.

In other words, it is copying the value of the variable `$value` to the attribute of the object `$object`.

Answer (score 0):

All this is doing is internally creating a new instance of it's creating a new instance of it's self for a form of recursion or other functionality,

so calling:

```
$object->$attribute
```

is essentially, from what I can see. Will create a new instance then depending on the contents of $attribute return a value or call a method